# Trying to use LAME on mp3- getting MPEG-2.5 is supported by Layer3 only

Tags: node.js, mp3, lame

When using the LAME interface through a node application (I am writing a JavaScript program running on node, with LAME installed), I am now getting this error on a semi-regular basis:

"MPEG-2.5 is supported by Layer3 only"

I am using LAME to convert mp3's to WAV files, so I need this to work for all mp3s.

What should I be doing to the mp3s (or to my call to LAME) to make these mp3 files convertible via LAME?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is often the result of someone who has taken an mp4 file and changed the name to mp3 extension. This shows up especially for windows, since it uses extensions to indicate file type rather than purely inspecting the file content.

In this case, using LAME to try to convert a file like (`helloworld.mp3` - which was originally `helloworld.mp4`):

```
LAME --decode helloworld.mp3 helloworld.wav
```

will give you the following message

```
"LAME error: MPEG-2.5 is supported by Layer3 only"
```